# Disk references not seen within build controller

Tags: c#, msbuild, continuous-integration

I have various projects which reference assemblies within `C:\Program Files (x86)`. I have installed the assemblies on my build controller in the exact same way and the files are in the `C:\`, however whenever I trigger a build my controller doesn't find the assemblies.

```
<Reference Include="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Diagnostics.v7, Version=7.0.6163.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

The reference in the project looks like the above, which in my opinion I can understand why the build controller can't find the reference because there are no hint paths.

I have tried changing `Copy Local` to `true` and `Specific Version` to `false`, this also didn't work. What should I change in my project, build controller or build definition to make the server have scope of the assemblies?

Comment: Is your build agent on the same machine as the build controller? If not, you need to install the references on the build agent. How did you install them? MSBuild looks for them in the GAC and if you just copy the files on the server, it can't find them there, as long as they are not in the GAC.

Comment: I agree with LukeH...  That looks like "I'm looking in the GAC".

Comment: @granadaCoder excuse my ignorance, what is `GAC`?

Comment: the GAC is a way to register "very commonly used" dlls.  and it allows to register the same dll under multiple versions.  (Which is why your reference tag is so very specific with "7.0.6163.0".  Is the dotnet replacement for COM registering.  That's the simple explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one way to solve this is to not reference from the GAC.

```
<Reference Include="GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Diagnostics.v7, Version=7.0.6163.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..., processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

1. Find this GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Diagnostics.v7.dll.
2. Where your .sln file resides, create a .\ThirdPartyReferences\ folder.
3. Copy GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Diagnostics.v7.dll to that directory.
4. Remove the "gac" reference.
5. Add the more local .\ThirdPartyReferences\ reference.
6. Check .\ThirdPartyReferences\ folder into source control.
7. Make sure .\ThirdPartyReferences\ is "pull down" from source control during the build.

OR

Get "GrapeCity.ActiveReports" installed on the build-server using their install tools.
Which should get into correctly into the GAC on the build server.

I usually choose the first option (my first option above).
I like having a very good handle on what my ThirdParty dependcies are for my build.

Comment: I have a development workspace which references the `C:\Program Files` etc. I have also installed the appropriate third party software on my build controller, it is the same location... I checked the logs, and it did resolve the path however the assembly name supposedly didn't exist. I have however got around this by essentially doing what you suggested with your 1st option.

Comment: Which is why I prefer the first option.  Sometimes the GAC reference-paths just drive you nuts.